# Changing URL breaking scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to change the url to that of the section id that is currently scrolled to. However my below code just breaks the scroll (it doesn't scroll at all).

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  $('section').each(function(){
    if ($(this).offset().top) {
      window.location.hash = $(this).attr('id');
    }
  });
});

<section id="a"></section>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<section id="b"></section>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<section id="c"></section>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<section id="d"></section>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: `$(this).attr('id')` it will return you the id like a, b, c, d but when you assign it to hash it suppose to start with #, so just concate it like `'#' + $(this).attr('id')` and then assign the value.

Comment: @PashaB, `location.hash` automatically adds the `#`.

Answer (score 2):

This line returns true for all `section`s except the first one:

```
if ($(this).offset().top)
```

Instead, you can compare each `section`'s offset against the window's scroll position:

```
if($(this).offset().top < $(window).scrollTop())
```

This line reloads the page, always scrolled to the last `section` (based on your current `if`):

```
window.location.hash = $(this).attr('id');
```

That's why it appears that scrolling is broken.

If you want to change the URL without reloading the page, use **[history.pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)**.

**Complete code:**

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  $('section').each(function() {
    if($(this).offset().top < $(window).scrollTop()) {
      history.pushState({}, '', '#'+$(this).attr('id'));
    }
  });
});
```